# C++ MSVS, what file "cleanup" should I be doing? (cl error: D8037)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild, build, visual-studio

Working in C++ MSVS2008, I've been having increasingly irritating problems: Breakpoints executing on the wrong line, not catching, etc.  It's a really large workspace with thousands of files, so I "put up with it".

I went through the "standard" stuff (clean, "deep" clean, manually delete `*.idb`, `*.pdb`, `*il*`, etc.)  It didn't fix the "breakpoint-on-wrong-line" problem, but things at least compiled and I could run/debug.

THEN, (for unrelated reasons), I created a command-line program that issued a compile-one-CPP-to-OBJ command, and got a strange error:

```
cl : Command line error D8037 : cannot create temporary il file; clean temp directory of old il files
```

I never heard of that before, so a web search got me to the Microsoft site that details the error:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385201(v=VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385201%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Um, Huh?  In my system `TMP` dir, there were apparently too many `_CL_hhhhhhhh.ss` files.  Searching, yes, I had exactly `6,063` of these files in that directory, going back about one year.

I've never heard of these files before ("temporary compiler files").  Searching the Microsoft site shows that this error is possible in *at least* MSVS 2005, 2008, 2010.  Being "temp" files, I assume there is some kind of "cleanup" or "recycle" algorithm?

- How many `_CL_hhhhhhhh.ss` files is the limit?  (I had this error under one condition at 6,063.)
- Why do I see this error when I execute a "compile" from within an EXE, and not from within the MSVS IDE?  (I don't see this error when I execute the "compile" directly from the command line either.)
- Should I be doing "maintenance" on my development machine by cleaning up files like these periodically?
- What other "cruft" files do I need to think about finding-and-removing?

As an aside, I'm aware that the MSVS project GUIDs are cached in the registry so that the IDE can "find" project files that are manually moved around to "repair" links/dependencies with other project files.  I'd like to know how to clean out those too, if anybody has a suggestion.

This *does* lead to the ultimate question of, **"What kinds of hidden cruft accumulates from using MSVS on a development machine?"**

Win7/64, C++ MSVS 2008, NTFS

Comment: Does the existence of these files pose a problem for you? What problem are you trying to solve? There's no particular reason to be concerned with files in a temporary directory unless you're running very low on disk space.

Comment: @Cody, I have plenty of disk space, but I can't compile the file from within-an-exe (cl error `D8037`)

Comment: @Cody, also confirmed: After manually deleting those files, rebuild, my breakpoints are on the correct line (I've been trying to fix that for days).

Comment: You can add a command to delete those files after a build if they keep recurring and causing problems, too

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the particular file you were having problems with was fairly large (greater than 10,000 lines), but I've had the same issue of breakpoints being on the wrong lines several times under that circumstance in MSVS2008.  The solution that worked for me (and improved the readability of the code) was to group a few of the functions logically into a class/namespace and put them into a new file.

Answer (score 1):

[cl.exe when launched via CreateProcess does not seem to have write permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560779/cl-exe-when-launched-via-createprocess-does-not-seem-to-have-write-permissions) addresses your second question. Why do you only see it when launched from within an exe?

It's most likely that cl.exe is failing elsewhere. If you use Process Monitor, it will give you a good idea on all the system calls made by cl.exe and what failed.

In my case, I was overriding the environment variables when calling CreateProcess and in that process ended up resetting SystemRoot environment variable. cl.exe uses it to resolve paths for some system dlls and as a result never ended up finding the dll.

The short term fix was to add "SystemRoot=c:\windows" to the environment settings I was passing into CreateProcess.

The right long term fix is the get the environment variables, parse them and only modify/append as required and pass that whole environment variables block to CreateProcess. That way, cl.exe launched via CreateProcess inherits the environment variables that your exe launched with.