# cl.exe when launched via CreateProcess does not seem to have write permissions

Tags: c, permissions, createprocess, cl.exe

I'm calling CreateProcess to launch cl.exe (VS2010 on Win7 64 bit). I get the following error..

cl : Command line error D8037 : cannot create temporary il file; clean temp directory of old il files

Calling the same command line with the same environment variables in a cmd window succeeds. I've checked the temp directory and there are no old files. It seems like the process that is created does not have write permissions. I've been trying different approaches.. CreateProcessAsUser, Set the security attributes to grant all standard permissions to the Everyone user group, with and without inheriting handles, etc. None of them seem to fix it.

And here's the basic code...

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof( SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES );
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

const char* _szSourceFile = "c:\\temp\\test\\src\\foo.cpp";

char szOptions[ 2048 ];
sprintf_s( szOptions, 
    "c:\\temp\\compile\\cl.exe "
    "/Gd "
    "/Fo\"c:\\temp\\test\\out\\\" "
    "/Fe\"c:\\temp\\test\\out\\\" "
    "/Fd\"c:\\temp\\test\\out\\\" "
    "/D \"WIN32\" "
    "/D \"_DEBUG\" "
    "/D \"_WINDOWS\" "
    "/D \"_USRDLL\" "
    "/D \"_WINDLL\" "
    "/D \"_MBCS\" "
    "/I\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Include\" "
    "/MDd "
    "/I\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\include\" "
    "/LDd "
    "%s "
    "c:\\temp\\test\\lib\\Uuid.Lib "
    "c:\\temp\\test\\lib\\oldnames.lib "
    "c:\\temp\\test\\lib\\msvcrtd.lib"
    , _szSourceFile );


STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof( STARTUPINFO ) );
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof( PROCESS_INFORMATION ) );
si.cb = sizeof( STARTUPINFO );

BOOL bSucceeded = CreateProcess( "c:\\temp\\compile\\cl.exe", szOptions, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, "PATH=c:\\temp\\Compile;%PATH%\0TEMP=c:\\temp\\test\\tmp\0\0", "c:\\temp\\test\\", &si, &pi );
```

In case you're wondering about the weird paths, I copied over the most minimal set of required tools, libs, etc to build a dll directly from a cpp file. The command in the code works on a regular command line with the path that is set in the enviroment variables block.

Also, in case you're wondering what this is for, I'm trying to have an app that can dynamically reload a dll. The app is being used for debugging/visualization and the idea is to be able to tweak the visualization code on the fly and have the app reload the dll.

I've been at this for 4 days googling and trying out different things. Any ideas?

Comment: The spawned process should have the same permission as the calling process; is the calling process able to create files in the temporary path?

Comment: Possibly the same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584811/c-msvs-what-file-cleanup-should-i-be-doing-cl-error-d8037

Comment: @PeterRitchie, Yes the calling process can create and write files in all the possible temp folders. I used GetEnvironmentVariable to get the locations for TMP as well as TEMP. Both point to c:\users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp folder. The 3rd folder is the TEMP var I pass into CreateProcess (TEMP=c:\temp\test\tmp).

Comment: @alk, Nope. None of my temp locations have those files mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the issue.

I used the Process Monitor to monitor cl.exe to see what was failing.
Process monitor can be downloaded from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.

Turns out that it was failing to load rsaenh.dll in the windows system folder. cl.exe could not resolve %SystemRoot% environment variable. Since I was overriding the environment variables, it got reset. **Adding SystemRoot=c:\Windows to the environment variables fixed it**. The proper fix would be to get the environment variables for the current process, parse and modify it to make your path additions and then pass that in. That way you inherit all the environment variables.

Comment: Adding "SystemRoot=c:\Windows" to the system environment worked for me thanks. But it needs windows restart.